# Prevent using Custom Keyboard from a node_module and use Native instead

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite

In my React Webapp, I have a package installed, that is using `react-simple-keyboard`.
I need this package, but I will use the native browser keyboard and **not** the custom react-simple-keyboard.

How can I prevent it from using `react-simple-keyboard`?
I have tried to go directly into the package through `node_modules` and removed the keyboard. But I don't see any changes.
I am using Vite, and have been trying restarting the server with `vite --force`. But I don't see any changes.

How is it possible to disable the native keyboard first of all? If just I could get that back, then `display: none` would be enough for the custom keyboard. When I look at the input fields in the DOM, it is not having the attribute *readonly*

Comment: Please provide more informations, which features do you need exactly from this package ? What is the actual problem with it ? The package let's you use methods and hooks without rendering the keyboard component itself, have you read the documentation ?

Comment: Its not really a feature. A package I've installed is using react-simple-keyboard. This means, that it will show their custom keyboard. I don't want that. It should use the native keyboard.

Comment: Then could you provide the actual name of this package ? I think that would help a lot, it's hard to tell you if there is perhaps a way to set that through options if you don't give the relevant info.